# 3-force in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, forces, vectors

Let's consider the definition of 3-force in different theories:

---

1. Newtonian mechanics

---

In Newtonian mechanics, we can define the force as a cause of changing momentum $p=m\vec{v}$ with time. According to the Second Newton law:
$$\vec{F} = \frac{d\vec{p}}{dt},$$
or in the coordinate form:
$$F^i = \frac{dp^i}{dt},$$
where $i = 1\ldots 3$, and $t$ -- is the absolute time here.

---

2. Special Relativity (SR) (let $c = 1$)

---

In Special Relativity the time is not absolute and it is better to formulate SR in Minkowsky space-time with metric:
$$ds = dt^2 - \delta_{ik}dx^idx^{k},$$
$i,k = 1 \ldots 3$.

Firstly, we can introduce 4-displacement vector $dx^{\mu}$:
$$dx^{\mu} =  (dt,-dx,-dy,-dz).$$

Secondly, we can introduce a 4-momentum  vector:
$$p^{\mu} = m\frac{dx^{\mu}}{ds}$$

And we can introduce 4-force as $$\mathcal{F}^{\mu} = \frac{dp^\mu}{ds}.$$

Now we want to introduce 3-force.

Firstly, the spatial components of 4-momentum are:
$$p^i = m\frac{dx^i}{ds}  = m\gamma \frac{dx^i}{dt}.$$

Secondly, the **spatial components of 4-force are not 3-force**:
$$\mathcal{F}^i = \frac{dp^i}{ds}  = \gamma \frac{dp^i}{dt},$$ where $\gamma^2 = \frac{1}{1 - v^2}$ and $t$ -- is coordinate time (not proper time).

Thirdly, to determine the 3-force, we need to remember the definition of force in Newtonian mechanics, there the force is equal to the change 3-momentum with time $F^i = \frac{dp^i}{dt}$, and from the last equation we conclude the relation between spatial components of 4-force and 3-force:
$$F^i = \frac{1}{\gamma}\mathcal{F}^i  = \frac{1}{\gamma}\frac{dp^i}{ds}.$$

---

4. General Relativity (GR)

---

In General Relativity (GR) the almost general form of metrics has a form:
$$ds^2  = g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu},$$
and 4-force is the covatiant derivative of 4-momentum (covariant derivative  necessary for 4-force to be a vector), and its **spatial** components are:
$$\mathcal{F^i} = m\frac{Dp^i}{ds}.$$

**How can I define 3-force in curved space?**

Comment: Along a geodesic in spacetime?  Yes.

Comment: @J. Murray I think no, because $\alpha$ is spatial index.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?  It's true for each component, spatial or temporal.

Comment: @J. Murray You want to say Landau was wrong? Because in his book he defines 3-force as $Dp^{\alpha}/ds$.

Comment: I suggest you read what I wrote.  $\frac{D p^\alpha}{ds}$ is equal to zero *along a geodesic in spacetime*.  When do particles follow spacetime geodesics?

Comment: @J. Murray only free particles follow geodesics

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @J.Murray But we still define an pseudo force of gravity, as described in book of Landau.

Comment: I still don't understand your question.  The force $f^\alpha = c\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}\frac{Dp^\alpha}{ds}$ is equal to zero along a spacetime geodesic.  If you want to break up the covariant derivative $\frac{Dp^\alpha}{ds}$ into $\frac{dp^\alpha}{ds} + m\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu \nu} \frac{du^\mu}{ds}\frac{du^\nu}{ds}$ and then treat the latter term as a pseudoforce, you're more than welcome to.

Comment: @J.Murray I have added the image from Landau book with problem. In the problem he define 3-force of gravity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67275/discussion-between-j-murray-and-sergio).